# Extract and save an image from a IplImage

Tags: c++, linux, opencv, iplimage, ximea

I'm working with a Ximea Camera, programming in c++ and using Ubuntu 14.04. I have a XI_IMG image and with the next conversion I'm creating an OpenCV image, copying data from xiAPI buffer to OpenCV buffer.

```
stat = xiGetImage(xiH, 5000, &image);
HandleResult(stat,"xiGetImage");    
XI_IMG* imagen = &image;

IplImage * Ima = NULL;
char fname_jpg[MAX_PATH] = "";
Ima = cvCreateImage(cvSize(imagen->width, imagen->height), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1); 
memcpy(Ima->imageData, imagen->bp, imagen->width * imagen->height);

imwrite("image1", Ima);
```

After doing that I should be able to save or show the image, but the next error is shown:

```
program.cpp:76:24:error:invalid initialization of reference of type 'cv::InputArray {aka const cv::_InputArray&}' from expression of type 'IplImage* {aka IplImage*}'
```

Is there any other way to obtain or save the image? What else can I do to save a jpg image?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are mixing old (and obsolete) C syntax like `IplImage*`, `cv<SomeFunction>()`, etc...  with current C++ syntax. 
To make it work be consistent and use only one *style*.

Using `IplImage`

```
int main()
{
    IplImage* img = NULL;
    img = cvCreateImage(...);

    // Save 
    cvSaveImage("myimage.png", img);

    // Show
    cvShowImage("Image", img);
    cvWaitKey();

    return 0;
}
```

Or using new syntax (**much better**):

```
int main()
{
    Mat img(...);

    // Save 
    imwrite("myimage.png", img);

    // Show
    imshow("Image", img);
    waitKey();

    return 0;
}
```

Note that you don't need to `memcpy` the data after you initialize your `Mat`, but you can call one of these constructors:

```
C++: Mat::Mat(int rows, int cols, int type, void* data, size_t step=AUTO_STEP)
C++: Mat::Mat(Size size, int type, void* data, size_t step=AUTO_STEP)
C++: Mat::Mat(int ndims, const int* sizes, int type, void* data, const size_t* steps=0)
```

Last trick, you can *wrap* your `IplImage` in a `Mat` and then use `imwrite`:

```
Mat mat(Ima);
imwrite("name.ext", mat);
```